# Getting an error with NIntegrate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral

Tags: numerical-integration

Hello I have the following problem. But when I try to solve it, I get an error   saying 'Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to \
insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral'

How can I resolve this? Increasing the WorkingPrecision does not help. Note that when I change the value of $\mu$ to 6.3096 it works.

```
α = 3;
δ = 2/α;

LI = Exp[-Expectation[
 Integrate[(1 - Exp[-x*h*r^(-1/δ)])*km*λ*π, {r,
    A, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False], 
 h \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, km > 0, 
   r > 0, λ > 
    0, {A, km, r, λ, α} ∈ Reals}]];

x = s*Ps;
A = r;
M = LI;

s = μ*r^α/Ps;
B = M;

λ = 20;
km = 0.5;
Ps = 0.2;
μ = 5.0119;

AverageProbSuccess = 
Assuming[{λ > 0, km > 0, 
Ps > 0, μ > 0, {km, Ps, λ, μ} ∈ Reals}, 
NIntegrate[
B*2*Gamma[λ + 1]/Gamma[λ]*
r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ), {r, 0, Infinity}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
α = 3;
δ = 2/α;

int = Assuming[{A > 0, km > 0, r > 0, λ > 0}, 
   Integrate[(1 - Exp[-x*h*r^(-1/δ)])*km*λ*π, {r, A, 
     Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]];
```

The condition suppressed by use of `GenerateConditions -> False` is `Re[h x] > 0`, so include assumption that `x > 0` and `FullSimplify` (this is quite slow) the expression for `LI` with the assumptions.

```
LI = Assuming[{A > 0, km > 0, r > 0, λ > 0, α ∈ Reals,
     x > 0},
   Exp[-Expectation[int, h \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]] // 
    FullSimplify];

x = s*Ps;
A = r;
M = LI;

s = μ*r^α/Ps;
B = M;

λ = 20;
km = 1/2;
Ps = 1/5;
μ = 5.0119;

AverageProbSuccess[B_, λ_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  B*2*Gamma[λ + 1]/Gamma[λ]*r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ), {r, 
   0, Infinity}]

AverageProbSuccess[B, λ]

(*  0.167891  *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working fine!